# Find count of occurrence of a row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with duplicate rows and I need to extract these duplicate rows alone. Below is an example of the table I have:

my_table:

```
ID   Offer  
1     10
2     10
1     12
1     10
2     20
2     10
```

What I want next is to count the occurrence of the offer for each ID. i.e, my final result should be:

```
ID    Offer    Count
1      10       1
2      10       1
1      12       1
1      10       2
2      20       1
2      10       2
```

As you can see, the count should increase based on the number of times the offer shows up per ID.

I tried something like:

```
select id,offer,count(offer) over (partition by id);
```

But this just gives the total count of that particular offer for that ID and is not the result I am looking for.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select id,offer,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id, offer order by rownum)
from tab
```